# What are some arguments to support the position that the Dojo JavasScript library is secure, accessible, and performant?

Tags: security, internationalization, dojo, accessibility

We have developed a small web application for a client. We decided on the Dojo framework to develop the app (requirements included were full i18n and a11y). Originally, the web app we developed was to be a "prototype", but we made the prototype production quality anyway, just in case. It turns out that the app we developed (or a variant of it) is going to production (many months hence), but it's so awesome that the enterprise architecture group is a little afraid.

508c compliant is a concern, as is security for this group. I now need to justify the use of Dojo to this architecture group, explicitly making the case that Dojo does not pose a security risk and that Dojo will not hurt accessibility (and that Dojo is there to help meet core requirements).

Note: the web app currently requires JavaScript to be turned on and a stylesheet to work. We use a relatively minor subset of Dojo: of course, dojo core, and dijit.form.Form, ValidationTextBox and a few others. We do use dojox.grid.DataGrid (but no drag N drop or editable cells, which are not fully a11y).

I have done some research of my own, of course, but I any information or advice you have would be most helpful.

Regards,
LES2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to answer this question except to point out that you'd be in good company using Dojo.  Several large corporations, deeply concerned about security issues have contributed to the toolkit and use it in their own products.  Audits have been done on the toolkit, including one recently which did expose a problem which was quickly patched -- in fact, the CDN feature of Dojo, if you use it, means you can pick up patches like this automatically.  Other than that, I'm not sure what proof to offer.  A toolkit is secure until someone finds a security hole!  Also, there are plenty of things you can do with Dojo, or the underlying HTML/JS technology, which are not secure.  You need to follow best practices.  One example is with JSON.  There are a couple of methods to handle JSON.  The base one is fast, works on older browsers, but is known not to be secure.  It is meant to be used only with trusted data sources, and typically with the same domain policy, that's what you'll be doing.  There are alternatives in dojox.secure which you might want to look at, depending on what you're doing, you may be able to provide an extra level of security to your application.

For performance, you can look at the various benchmarks like [taskspeed](http://dante.dojotoolkit.org/taskspeed/), which focus largely on the dojo.query DOM traversal functionality common to most toolkits.  Of course, YMMV depending on your usage of Dojo, but there's healthy competition between the toolkits and continuous improvement with each release.

For accessibility, all Dijit widgets were reviewed and considered to be 508c compliant.  There is more precise documentation on [Dojo/Dijit a11y requirements](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit-a11y-req). Not all dojox widgets pass this requirement.

HTH